# Getting Max across 3 columns in C# Deedle Dataframe

Tags: c#, pandas, deedle

I'm attempting to convert some pandas code over to Deedle and C#.

First the dataframe is <DateTime, string> since it's indexed on date.

```
Frame.FromRecords(fetchOhlcVsResults).IndexRows<DateTime>("datetime").SortRowsByKey()
```

Next I'm successfully adding several other computed columns in the frame. The part I'm stuck on translating is this snippet from pandas:

```
tr = df[['high-low', 'high-pc', 'low-pc']].max(axis=1)
```

Which just takes the max from across the row of the three columns.
Here's what I've tried:

```
var tr = df.Columns[new[] { "high_low", "high_pc", "low_pc" }].IndexRows<DateTime>("datetime").SortRowsByKey();
```

Which gives me a new dataframe. Not sure where to go from here.

Ultimately I'd like to add the resulting series as a new column to the original dataframe.

```
df.AddColumn("tr", tr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem, the question is how to calculate maximum across (some of) the columns of the data frame rather than over the rows (which is what the `axis` argument seems to be specifying in pandas).

In this case, I would use the `Select` operation on the data frame to apply a function to each row. You can then select the columns you need and calculate the maximum over those.

```
var data = new[] {
  new { Date=new DateTime(2020,1,1), Hi1=10, Hi2=15 },
  new { Date=new DateTime(2020,1,2), Hi1=12, Hi2=11 } };
var df = Frame.FromRecords(data).IndexRows<DateTime>("Date");
var max = df.Rows.Select(r => r.Value[new[] { "Hi1", "Hi2" }].Max());
df.AddColumn("Hi", max);
df.Print();
```

This calculates the "Hi" column in the following data frame:

```
              Hi1 Hi2 Hi
01/01/2020 -> 10  15  15
02/01/2020 -> 12  11  12
```